# MySQL delete duplicate records but keep one based on date

Tags: mysql

how to delete all the records with same email address but keep the latest one by date? the date formate in MySQL is "0000-00-00". I have the follow query:

```
delete from customer
 where date not in (
    select max(data)
      from customer
     group by email)
```

seems not working.

and can you please show how to just keep one record based on nothing, since my records don't have `id`.

Comment: It may well be faster to CREATE a new table by selecting just the desired rows

Answer (score -1):

Join with a subquery that gets the latest date for each customer.

```
DELETE c1 FROM customer AS c1
JOIN (SELECT email, MAX(date) AS maxdate
      FROM customer
      GROUP BY email) AS c2
ON c1.email = c2.email AND c1.date != c2.maxdate
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but since I got more than 100,000 records in one table, I tried few query like this then the system stucks.

Comment: Try adding an index: `ALTER TABLE customer ADD INDEX (email, date)`

Comment: man, it shows this error :    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE c1 FROM customer AS c1 JOIN (SELECT customer, MAX(memb' at line 2

Comment: If the error is near `DELETE`, that sounds like you have an unterminated statement before this.